# Error with XSLT XPATH (Expression must evaluate to a node-set)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

**I have XML like the follows**

```
<Employees>

  <Employee>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <FirstName>Bala</FirstName>
    <LastName>Murugan</LastName>
    <Dept>Production Support</Dept>
  </Employee>

  <Employee0>
    <ID>101</ID>
    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
    <LastName>Laurence</LastName>
    <Dept>Development</Dept>
  </Employee0>

  <Employee1>
    <ID>102</ID>
    <FirstName>Rick</FirstName>
    <LastName>Anderson</LastName>
    <Dept>Sales</Dept>
  </Employee1>

</Employees>
```

**I would like to show one of those employees using the following XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="SLCT"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$SLCT">
      <div style="border:1px black solid;width:300px;margin:1px">
        <div>
          <b>Employee ID:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Name:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b>Department:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="Dept"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem with (for-each select="$SLCT"), It does'nt accept parameter from C#.

**my C# code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strXSLTFile = Server.MapPath("EmployeeXSLT.xslt");
    string strXMLFile = Server.MapPath("Employess.xml");

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);
    XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);

    // Create the XsltArgumentList.
    XsltArgumentList argList = new XsltArgumentList();
    // Set new value to the parameter
    argList.AddParam("SLCT", "", "(//Employee)[1]");
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Server.MapPath("OutPut.xml"));
    objXSLTransform.Transform(new XPathDocument(strXMLFile), argList, writer); 
    //Expression must evaluate to a node-set
    writer.Close(); 
    reader.Close();
    Xml2.DocumentSource = Server.MapPath("~/test/Employess.xml");
    Xml2.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("~/test/OutPut.xml");
    Xml2.DataBind();
}
```

I got this exception as commented in the code (//Expression must evaluate to a node-set). However, when I use "(//Employee)[1]" or "//Employee" directly in the XSLT file instead of using the parameter (SLCT), I get the needed result. So, where is the problem here?

Comment: Who on earth thought that it was a smart idea to use a different element name for each Employee? It would be hard to think of a design choice that makes processing five times harder and has absolutely no compensating benefits,

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression used in the `select` attribute of `xsl:for-each` instruction cannot be calculated dynamically at runtime.

Since your XML uses a different element name for each employee record (`Employee`, `Employee0`, `Employee1`, etc.), you could pass the wanted element's name as the parameter and then select the correct element using a predicate.

For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="SLCT"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <xsl:variable name="emp" select="*[name()=$SLCT]" />
    <div>
      <b>Employee ID:</b>
      <xsl:value-of select="$emp/ID"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when called with the value of `"Employee0"` for the `SLCT` parameter, will return:

**Result**

```
<div><b>Employee ID:</b>101</div>
```

---

**Note**:
Since only a single element will satisfy the predicate, I have used a variable instead of `xsl:for-each`. But it would have worked just as well using:

```
<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[name()=$SLCT]">
        <div>
          <b>Employee ID:</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your XML needs some improvement. There is no need to have different XML element names for each employee. And you can retrieve a particular employee based on the unique ID element value: 100, 101, etc. I adjusted the XSLT to accept that type of parameter. Check it out below.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <FirstName>Bala</FirstName>
        <LastName>Murugan</LastName>
        <Dept>Production Support</Dept>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <ID>101</ID>
        <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
        <LastName>Laurence</LastName>
        <Dept>Development</Dept>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <ID>102</ID>
        <FirstName>Rick</FirstName>
        <LastName>Anderson</LastName>
        <Dept>Sales</Dept>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="SLCT">100</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/Employee[ID=$SLCT]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <div style="border:1px black solid;width:300px;margin:1px">
            <div>
                <b>Employee ID:</b>
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>Name:</b>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(FirstName,' ',LastName)"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>Department:</b>
                <xsl:value-of select="Dept"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> c#

```
// Set new value to the parameter
argList.AddParam("SLCT", "", "101");
```

> Output

```
<div style="border:1px black solid;width:300px;margin:1px">
  <div>
    <b>Employee ID:</b>101
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Name:</b>Peter Laurence
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Department:</b>Development
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't make up your own question.

Comment: Let's wait for a response from the OP.